# Google Charts - Vertical axis separators / dividers

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using google charts to show a really basic horizontal bar graph.

How can I add the separator / divider on the vAxis? I've played around with the gridlines, checked the docs (I'm probably missing it somewhere) and I can't seem to find anything that could help.

I know this is possible with other chart libraries because I've done it before but I'm stuck with google charts due to a plugin (this is being created in WordPress).

What I need:

[image]

What I got:

[image]

What options for the chart should I be working with or do I need to do some sort of workaround? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
var options = {
    height:300 ,
    bar: { 
        groupWidth: '80%' 
    },
    backgroundColor: '#EEEEEE',
    isStacked: true,
    series: {
        1:{color:'#dfe8f2', opacity: 0.5}
    },
    hAxis: {
        baselineColor: 'none',
        ticks: []
    },
    vAxis: {
        baselineColor: 'none',
        ticks: [],
    },
    legend: { 
        position: 'none' 
    },
    tooltip : {
        trigger: 'none'
    }
};
```

Comment: no option available, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56650338/5090771) is a similar answer...

Comment: Awesome thanks, I will check it out